# PHP preg_match for multi language

Tags: php, preg-match

```
preg_match( '/^[-A-Za-z0-9\p{Han}]+$/u', $name)
```

This will work only for Chinese character, I need it to check for all languages.
Any suggestions?

I tried below command. It works for some language but, doesn't work for all.

```
preg_match('/^[-A-Za-z0-9\p{L} ]+$/u', $name)
```

**EDIT**

The exact requirement will be: if the string contains any symbol, replace it with `_`; while allowing multi language content.

Comment: Do you mean `\p{Letter}`?

Comment: I have tested for Hindi, Chinese and Japanese. It worked for Chinese and Japanese, but didn't for Hindi

Comment: It looks right to me, but you did not include a diacritic pattern. Try also adding `\p{M}`. `'/^[-\p{N}\p{L}\p{M}\s]+$/u'` or - to avoid matching digits - `'/^[-\p{L}\p{M}\s]+$/u'`. Could you please share *exact* requirements? What is *character* here? Letters/digits/diacritics/spaces/hyphens/apostrophes? Please **be more specific** when asking regex questions.

Comment: The exact requirement will be: if the string contains any symbol, replace it with _; while allowing multi language content.

Comment: Any symbol is matched with `\p{S}`. Try `preg_replace('~\p{S}~u', '_', $s)`. If you want to also match punctuation, add `\p{P}`: `~[\p{P}\p{S}]~u`. If you want to avoid matching `-` with that, use `~(?!-)[\p{P}\p{S}]~u`

Answer (score 0):

> The exact requirement will be: if the string contains any symbol, replace it with `_`; while allowing multi language content.

So, you need to use `preg_replace` that replaces all non-overlapping occurrences of a pattern with a defined replacement string, and the pattern to match a symbol is `\p{S}`. Do not forget `u` UNICODE modifier.

```
preg_replace('~\p{S}~u', '_', $s);
```

Now, if you also plan to match and remove punctuation chars (POSIX character class [`[:punct:]`](https://regex101.com/r/Muqldx/1) includes both punctuation and symbols) with the exception of `-`, you may use

```
preg_replace('~(?!-)[[:punct:]]~u', '_', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Muqldx/2).

Here, `(?!-)` negative lookahead will restrict the more generic `[[:punct:]]` pattern that matches any punctuation and symbol chars forcing the regex engine to exclude `-` from matching.

You may add more exceptions this way if necessary.